# Duplicate ContentPlaceHolder error for non-admins, but not admins

Tags: custom-masterpage

I have a custom master page for a staff directory. It was a modification of the minimal.master that I've named search.master. I thought everything was fine, until one of the normal users told me they can't see the staff directory. They get the following error: "Duplicate ContentPlaceHolder 'PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb' were found. ContentPlaceHolders require unique IDs."

The problem is, I've searched through my search.master, and there's only one reference to PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb. I can't figure out why only non-admin users would see this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ooops. It was a mistake. I had not published the newest version. I had only checked it in. So regular users were seeing the published older incorrect version of the master page.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake. I had not published the newest version. I had only checked it in. So regular users were seeing the published older incorrect version of the master page.